# Receive data from other app through intent-filter kotlin?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-jetpack-navigation

MainActivity

```
 val isActivityLaunchedFromActionSend = intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND
    val isActivityLaunchedFromActionSendMultiple = intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
    val isTextData = intent.type?.startsWith("text/") == true
    val isImageData = intent.type?.startsWith("image/") == true
    if (isActivityLaunchedFromActionSend && isTextData) {

        // Session 1: Handle received text data
        val sentString = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)

       //Sending data to fragment so we can set the value in edittext.
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("message", sentString)

        val fragInfo = HomeFragment()
        fragInfo.setArguments(bundle)
      
    } else if (isActivityLaunchedFromActionSend && isImageData) {

        // Session 2: Handle received image data
        val sentImageURI = intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) as? Uri

    } else if (isActivityLaunchedFromActionSendMultiple && isImageData) {
        val imageURIList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM) ?: arrayListOf()           
    }
```

HomeFragment

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val myValue =requireArguments().getString("message")
    etUrl.setText(myValue)
```

Here the value in myValue is coming null. And In HomeFragment there is one editText So when the user sends a link to my app the link will automatically past in EditText.

Manifests

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

So can you please tell me what things I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are never using `HomeFragment`. In an `if` block, you have `val fragInfo = HomeFragment()`, put the arguments on that fragment... and then never do anything with `fragInfo`. So, that `HomeFragment` instance and its arguments will get garbage collected.

Comment: I am not able to understand what exactly you are trying to say so if it possible can you change in code?

Comment: @BhavyaVarmora: "if it possible can you change in code? " -- no, because the code is not in your question. Somewhere, you have created *two* `HomeFragment` instances. One -- the one shown in your first code snippet -- is useless, as you do nothing with it. The second is the one that actually sets up your UI, and it does not have the arguments with your text. Find where your second `HomeFragment` is being created, then decide how you want to merge that code with what you have in the first code snippet.